# Simple way of copying a file to a remote box via SCP using a Rake Task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm used to Python Fabric in the past and I'm trying to do something similar with Ruby.

Basically I have created a Rake script which will run as a particular user which has SSH keys setup for passwordless access to the boxes in question.

I've managed to use https://github.com/seattlerb/rake-remote_task in order to run a command remotely, and expected the "put" method to "just work". However it seems to be an Rsync wrapper which does not take advantage of the keyless authentication.

It also seems to expect the file to be generated by a template which is not what I want, I want to SCP an actual .tgz binary file.

Am I missing something in the Ruby/Rake ecosystem. I expected this to be easy, but I feel like I'm going to need to go back to searching for gems?

Comment: i just used system() and shelled out. i dunno why i thought i needed some fancy gem

Comment: Just use `system` or `spawn` to call `scp`.